# How do I hide a partcular part of the border?

Tags: html, css

I am making a solar system, and I'm stuck at Saturn. I am trying to make a ring of the Saturn but I'm facing an issue. Everything is done but i need to hide the border which must come at the back of the planet and also it should not be visible. I need to hide only a particular part of the border.
You see the blue border, I need only enough border so that it is not visible and it must look like a saturn ring. This is just a test, it is not a real project!

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.big {
  width:  170px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: teal;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: 129px;

}

.saturn-ring {
  width:  90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  border-right: 2px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  transform: skew(295deg, 309deg);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="big"> </div>
<div class="saturn-ring"> </div>
```

"I NEED THIS TO BE A SATURN RING AND I'M TRYING TO MAKE SATURN. DOES ANYONE KNOW HOW I CAN DO THIS???"

I tried to hide the right and bottom border but it is not helping. Rather it hides the whole border and it leaves an uneven space which does not look like Saturn:::::

Comment: It's more complicated than that. These elements need to be layered and perspective might be needed to introduce a 3d method. I would suggest you invest in more research.

Comment: For the  the right and bottom border you can use the color ```teal``` that's one way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by separating the red and blue rings and using z-index.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        .big{
            width:  170px;
            height: 170px;
            background-color: teal;
            border-radius: 50%;
            position: relative;
            left: 50px;
            z-index: 1;

        }
        .saturn-ring-blue{
        position: absolute;
        width:  90px;
        height: 90px;
        border-top: none;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: 2px solid blue;
        border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
        transform: skew(295deg, 309deg);
        border-radius: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        }
        .saturn-ring-red{
        position:absolute;
        width:  90px;
        height: 90px;
        border-top: 2px solid red;
        border-left: 2px solid red;
        border-right: none;
        border-bottom: none;
        transform: skew(295deg, 309deg);
        border-radius: 50%;
        z-index: 999;
        left: 50%;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="big">  </div>
        <div class="saturn-ring-blue">
        </div>
        <div class="saturn-ring-red">
        </div>

</body>
> </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution.

Create two divs, one for red and one for blue. Then position them using z-index and position relative.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.saturn{
  position:relative;
}

.big {
  width:  170px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: teal;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: 129px;

}

.saturn-ring-red{
  width:  90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  transform: skew(295deg, 309deg);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position:relative;
  top:52px;
}

.saturn-ring-blue{
  width:  90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-right: 2px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  transform: skew(295deg, 309deg);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
  top:-40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="big"> </div>
<div class="saturn">
<div class="saturn-ring-red"></div>
<div class="saturn-ring-blue"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```css
    body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .big {
      width:  170px;
      height: 170px;
      background-color: teal;
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: relative;
    }

    .saturn {
      position:relative;
    }

    .saturn::before,.saturn::after {
      content:"";
      display:block;
      position:absolute;
      width:  90px;
      height: 90px;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) skew(295deg, 309deg);
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .saturn::before {
      border-right: 2px solid blue;
      border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
    }
    
    .saturn::after {
      border-top: 2px solid red;
      border-left: 2px solid red;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="saturn">
      <div class="big"> </div>
    </div>
```